# How to sort a ListView bound to an XML datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to sort the list view by a certain XML Element.

Here is my aspx code which shows how the listview is set up:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="newsDataSource">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="ItemPlaceHolderContainer" runat="server">
            <span id="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%# XPath("title") %></h2>
        <p><%# XPath("contents") %></p>
        <p>Author: <%# XPath("author") %></p>
        <p>Date Time: <%# XPath("datetime") %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="myDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/Data.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<theNews>
  <news>
    <title>Welcome!</title>
    <contents>Hello, and welcome!</contents>
    <author>Me</author>
    <datetime>6/11/2014 4:40:35 PM</datetime>
  </news>
</theNews>
```

What I want to do is sort the content in the ListView according to the 'datetime' XML element. Anyone know how I can do this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Sort me here!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line into your Layout Template, either manually or add it to your code to populate it within the ItemPlaceHolder.

> ```
>   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByDateTime" 
>             CommandName="Sort" Text="Date Time" CommandArgument="datetime"/>
> ```